# Android ImageView DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding

In my application I've got a lot of variables whose values are received throught BLE.

In the layout I've got some ImageViews (A simple image of a LED) which should change if the related variable change.

I thought using DataBinding would be a good idea, so I prepared the layout and the class to work with it.

I've already worked with data bind and i know how to change textViews "Text" field if the variable change.

**How can i change the ImaveView app:srccompact value if a boolean variable change?**

I already tried in this way but it result in a compilation error:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImgEVdiscesa"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@{idraulica.EVDiscesa?@drawable/ic_radio_button_checked_light_green_a700_24dp:@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp}"
                     />
```

Comment: boolean variable? what boolean variable?

Comment: I've got a boolean variable in the class binded to the View.   In the Example i posted the variabile is "EVDiscesa" inside "idraulica"

Comment: simply use @{idraulica.EVDiscesa} and inside `getEVDiscesa()` method return either R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_light_green_a700_24dp or R.drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp, see [Observable Objects](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#observable_objects)

Comment: Thanks it works! :)

Comment: sure, it must work... of course you added `setEVDiscesa` method with `notifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: Yes i did ;) thanks

Comment: If one of you could post an answer with the code example it would be lovely :) @L.Gangemi

Comment: @ItayFeldman it was a year ago and I do not have the project with this code anymore, anyway I solved the problem thanks to pskink answer. If I remember correctly the bindings refers to the getter method for working, so I just handled the change inside the getter.  I hope I have been helpful.